# How can I disable products so they are unpurchase-able and also display in a view?

Tags: views, commerce

I have a view of published products. I want to also create a view of unpublished products, so users can see previous products that were available, but there shouldn't be an *Add to cart* button on these products.

I've unpublished the products and created a view. Administrator users can see the view; when they click on one on the products, the *Add to cart* button is still there.

How can I avoid products can be purchased and displayed in a view?

Comment: I wouldn't use "unpublishing" for this.  Generally, in Drupal, "unpublished" nodes should not be shown unless the user is an admin.  Depending on the type of product, you can add a new boolean field such as "available" and then set that to false for the products you are no longer selling, and then configure your view based on that field.

Answer (score 2):

What you do is somewhat dependent on your product architecture, specifically which fields you have at the Product level and which at the ProductVariation level. If all the fields you use in your product displays are at the Product level, you can simply disable the ProductVariation and leave the Product published. There will no longer be an Add to Cart form on the display, and everything else will remain the same.

Use a little trial and error to see what works for you. You may need some additional site building or theming in the case that your displays are dependent on fields injected from the ProductVariation into the Product display.